# Diagonalizable Matrix with Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a given 3 x 3 diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues ${2,3,5}$ and let $\lambda$ be a number which is not an eigenvalue

1. Show that A commutes with the inverse of $(A - \lambda I)$
2. Let B be any matrix which commutes with A. Show that B commutes with the inverse of $(A - \lambda I)$

I found the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ to be $1/2, 1/3,$ and $1/5$. But I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm pretty sure I use the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Show your work and use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I found the eigenvalues of A^{-1} to be 1/2, 1/3, and 1/5. But I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm pretty sure I use the eigenvalues of A^{-1} but I'm not sure how.

Comment: For the commuting part you can start trying to rewrite $A-\lambda I$ with diagonalization. You can assume that $A = TDT^{-1}$ since it is given that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: So if A = TDT^(-1) then A^(-1) = T^(-1)D^(-1)T correct?

Comment: Not correct; multiply the two together and you see that things don't cancel.